# Parse curl output with jq and compare in unix shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, exec, puppet

Can someone help me why I am getting this error:

Error:

```
  ~> /bin/bash -c [[ $(curl -s  -H "Application: application/json" "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1" | jq .'["userId"]' ) == "1"]]
1: -c: line 1: unexpected token `EOF' in conditional command
1: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

This is the API output:

```
  ~> curl -s  -H "Application: application/json" "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false

  ~> curl -s  -H "Application: application/json" "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1" | jq .'["userId"]'
1
```

I am trying to use this shell command in puppet Exec.

Update:

```
/bin/bash -c 'test `curl -s  -H "Application: application/json" "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1" | jq .'["userId"]'` == "1"'
jq: error: userId/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.[userId]
jq: 1 compile error
(23) Failed writing body
/bin/bash: line 0: test: ==: unary operator expected
```

Got it:

```
/bin/bash -c "test `curl -s  -H \"Application: application/json\" \"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1\" | jq .'[\"userId\"]'` == \"1\""
```

Thanks James

Comment: Your API output isn't valid JSON.

Comment: And you should quote the argument to `bash -c`.

Comment: update the output, found another error with jq.

Comment: The first single quote inside the string ends the quoting. Using both single and double quotes inside something you quote is tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is incorrect `bash` syntax, not `curl` or `jq` -- of course there could be problems with those as well, but first things first...  Error reasons:

1. Because of the `-c` option, the double brackets need single quotes.
2. A space   is required before a closing double bracket `]]`.

Simple example; test if *5* equals *5*:

No single quotes fails:

```
bash -c [[ 5 == 5 ]]
```

Output:

```
5: -c: line 1: unexpected token `EOF' in conditional command
5: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

No space before `]]` fails:

```
bash -c '[[ 5 == 5]]'
```

Output:

```
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for `]]'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Success:

```
bash -c '[[ 5 == 5 ]]'
```

Applying that to the OP code:

```
/bin/bash -c '[[ $(curl -s  -H "Application: application/json" "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1" | jq .'["userId"]' ) == "1" ]]'
```